# How do I add a PayPal API request call?

Tags: api, paypal, woocommerce

We are using Woocommerce along with PayPal Pro on our website.

We are using the CloudIQ basket abandonment system and need to add a PayPal API request call to be made after the customer completes the checkout process.

Does anybody know if this is possible in PayPal and how I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about your exact request. But if you are referring to the data collection API call in PayPal, you can refer to the link below about PayPal Instant Payment Notification (IPN).
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/
In addition, PayPal have Classic API and REST API for your reference in the link below.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/